# Android HTC sense 4 and HTC sense 5 - answer incoming call feature doesnt work

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, htcsense, sense

Hi i write app that answers incoming call on press my overlayed button . this working perfect on android 4.0.3 - 4.3 but not on HTC sense 4  and HTC sense 5 .
Anybody know how to bring in life this function for HTC sense ?

thanks a lot )

code i use in regular android for call acceptation :
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static void answerIncomingCall(Context context) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Not worked for HTC sense. after i modified a bit and this worked on HTC openSens emulator but didnt work on real HTC sense 5 and 4 :

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static void answerIncomingCallHTC(Context context)  {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP ,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

i also tried to use open Sesne APi in HTCDev portal. And found two possible options but both didn't work also :(

1st :

```
PhoneCallUIService.PhoneCallUIState phone = new PhoneCallUIState(context);
phone.setCallState( PhoneCallUIService.PhoneCallUIState.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK);
```

but got no class found exception ....

2nd:
I tried to bind their open.phone service but i didn't succeed to do bound to the service

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static void answerIncomingCallHTC(Context context)  {

    /// Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() 
    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            Log.d(TAG,"binding htc service");
            mService = (PhoneCallUIService) service;
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
            Log.d(TAG,"disconnected from htc service");
        }
    };


    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PhoneCallUIService.class);
    context.bindService(intent, mConnection,  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(mBound) {
        Log.d(TAG,"before htc call");
        mService.performAction(PhoneCallUIService.ACTION_ANSWER_CALL, 1, new Bundle());
        Log.d(TAG,"after htc call");

    }
    else 
        Log.d(TAG,"the htc service not bounded");


    }

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

It really eat my mind. Please help.

Tnx.